# MVC with EF5rc model in separate projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am trying to get up to speed on EF5 and MVC so please bear with me.
Using EF 5rc and MVC4 in a DB first environment.

I would like to place the EF code in a seperate project so that I can make it reusable for other projects.

What I am looking for are examples or samples of how to work the seperate DLL from the EF project into the model portion of the MVC project.

I'm confused on how to create the context, in the RF project or in the MVC project?

Any other tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Create a library project to hold the EF data access implementation
2. Create a MVC 4 project
3. Reference the EF project with a project reference from the MVC project
4. New up contexts as needed in the MVC project

[This blog post](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/04/24/automatic-migrations-with-entity-framework-4-3) has a detailed description of how to go about this. There's also a [screencast](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/05/18/screencast-automatic-migrations-with-entity-framework-4-3). It uses Code First, but just yank out that part in favor of your Database First stuff.